# adding values to listbox from the drop down selected item

Tags: asp.net

The code is from usercontrol

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>Maer</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Cor</asp:ListItem>
```

En

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Style="font-size: small; width: 70px; font-weight:    lighter" Text="Add" OnClick="btn1_click" />

 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="220px">                       </asp:ListBox>
```

javascript function

```
function btn1_click()
 {
```

How do I get the values from dropdown and add to listbox?

Comment: SELECTED items from DropDownList2 or ALL items?

Comment: selected items from dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#btn1").click(function (event) {

    var $ddl = $("#MC_ucOperations_DropDownList2"); Getting the id of the dropdown
    var $list = $("#MC_ucOperations_ListBox2"); // Getting the id of the listbox 

    var selValue = $ddl.val();
    var selText = $ddl.find("option:selected").text();

    var $opt = $("<option></option>");
    $opt.html(selText);
    $opt.attr("value", selValue);

    $list.append($opt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add the current selected item of DropDownList2 and add it to ListBox2 using JavaScript. This code is executed on the Client/Browser side after Btn1 is clicked:

**JavaScript:**

```
function btn1_click() {
    var mylistRef = document.getElementById('<%= ListBox2.ClientID %>');

    var selectedItemValue = document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').options[document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').selectedIndex].value;
    var selectedItemText = document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').options[document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').selectedIndex].text;

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = selectedItemText;
    option.value = selectedItemValue;
    option.innerText = selectedItemText;
    mylistRef.options.add(option);
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem value="1">Maer</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="2">Cor</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick="btn1_click()" />

<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="220px" />
```

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %> option:selected

Comment: Lucidold ,thanks for the response . I have other question too you are geting the value selectedItem  and not using in the code? do i have replace response with selecteditem?

Comment: What do you mean by response? What are you trying to do??

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is null or undefined

Comment: Please update your code in your question. Not sure what you have done so far, so I cant help you much. The code I have in my answer works perfectly for me.

Comment: The javacript file is under folder solution-->static -->scrpts--> opddsata.js . This file is called from usercontrol and the user control is declared in aspx page . Do you think the above error is due to jquery?

Comment: You should put the JavaScript inside the ASPX page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55871/discussion-between-user2465036-and-lucidgold).